# Calculate Average given two Values which determine a Range and Map in to another Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I want to do some calculations, but I dont know how I can implement the idea. Given the example below:

[image: Example-Picture]

I have two numeric values `(here: 1960 and 1965)`.
Based on these two numeric values, in the column "H" all the years should be marked as a range `(i.e. H2:H6)`. And based on this range, excel should take the value from the column polcon_REV and apply the average-function to it.

Does anyone have an idea how to realize that?

---

***This solution worked for me (MITTELWERTWENNS = GERMAN FOR AVERAGEIF)***

```
=(MITTELWERTWENNS($F:$F;$D:$D;">="&$H$3;$D:$D;"<="&$I$3;$C:$C;J3))
```

The last criteria checks a meanhwile introduced third criteria for the different countries for which i have to calculate the average.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  You could use a filter; subtotal; aggregate, averageifs, and a number of other approaches.  And what do you mean by `marked as a range`?  I don't see anything marked in column H.

Comment: I figured it out with averagifs.

Answer (score 1):

[Try AverageIf function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-averageif-function)

```
 =AVERAGEIF(H1:H36000,$L$3,J1:J36000)
```

Let us know how you get on

Comment: If placing in Cell L4   "=Averageif(h1:h36000,$L$3,J1:h36000)". Not sure how long your data goes so guessed upto 36,000th row.

Comment: As the averageif function is not an array formula, one can use full column references.  `=AVERAGEIF(H:H,$L$3,J:J)`